# Redirection One Model to Another

Tags: redirect, yii

So, I am having a problem in yii, let's say i created an information and when i click save i want it to redirect to another form in another model. So here's how it goes

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new SessionOne;
    $SessionTwo = new SessionTwo;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['SessionOne']) && isset($_POST['SessionTwo']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['SessionOne'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->session_one_id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

So how should I do it in $this->redirect(array());

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(isset($_POST['SessionOne']) && isset($_POST['SessionTwo']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['SessionOne'];
            if($model->save()) {
                $this->render('application.views.your_view', array('id'=>$model->session_one_id, 'model'=> $SessionTwo));
            } else {
                print_r($model->getErrors()); // show error
            }
        } else {
            $this->render('create',array(
               'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: i tried this one but still its not working, it redirects to the same page and doesn't save my first model